# Framework for arcade game

Tags: javascript, html, framework, game-development

I would like to write an arcade game ("clone" of *River Raid* game) in JavaScript, using `<canvas>` HTML element. And I'm looking for an HTML5 game framework for this purpose.

I need:

- loader screen
- keyboard handling (arrow keys and space)
- animated sprites
- collision detection

I don't need WebGL (properly I would like to choose between WebGL render and Canvas renderer).

It will be also be nice if I could write a bot for this game (I need it for a project).

I've heard about Create.js but I don't know if it is good for my game. I have some experience with PIXI.js (without any other libraries) and tried to write a game with it but I got stucked after a few weeks.

Answer (score 3):

[melonJS](http://melonjs.org/) is a fresh & lightweight HTML5 game engine, which currently has the following features:

- A fresh & lightweight 2D sprite-based engine
- Standalone library (does not rely on anything else, except a HTML5 capable browser)
- Compatible with most major browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, IE) and mobile devices
- Device motion & accelerometer support
- High DPI & auto scaling
- Multi-channel HTML5 audio support and Web Audio on supported devices
- Lightweight physics implementation to ensure low cpu requirements
- Polygon (SAT) based collision algorithm for accurate detection and response
- Fast Broad-phase collision detection using spatial partitioning
- 3rd party tools support for physic body definition (PhysicEditor, Physic Body Editor)
- Advanced math API for Vector and Matrix
- Tween Effects
- Transition effects
- A basic set of Object Entities (to be extended)
- Object Pooling
- Basic Particle System
- Basic animation management
- Standard spritesheet and Packed Textures (Texture Packer, ShoeBox) support
- A state manager (to easily manage loading, menu, options, in-game state)
- Tiled map format version +0.9.x integration for easy level design
- Uncompressed Plain, Base64, CSV and JSON encoded XML tilemap loading
- Orthogonal, Isometric and Perspective tilemap support
- Multiple layers (multiple background/Foreground, collision and Image layers)
- Multiple Tileset support
- Tileset Transparency settings
- Layers Alpha settings - Rectangle, Ellipse, Polygon and Polyline objects support
- Tiled Objects
- Flipped & rotated Tiles
- Dynamic Layer and Object/Group ordering
- Dynamic Entity loading
- Shape based Tile collision support
- System & bitmap fonts
- Mouse and Touch device support (with mouse emulation)
- Built-in support for [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/)
- Asynchronous messaging support (minPubSub)
- Basic GUI elements included
- Customizable loader